# Why Does My CSS Code in <style scoped> Apply Globally?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to link bootstrap stylesheets to and only to a specific table.  I read up on the `<style scoped>@import url()<style>` trick online and tried to apply it to my code.  The CSS code I have written inside of the `<style scoped>` block, however, still applies globally.  Why is that? Is it a browser issue?  Are there other ways to link stylesheets to local elements only? Thank you!

Here is my trial code:

```
<style>
    h2{
        font-family: monospace};
    body{
        font-family:cursive};
</style>
<h2> This is monosapce </h2>
<p> This is curisve font. </p>
    <table data-toggle = "table" data-classes="table table-hover">
        <style scoped>
            @import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css);
            @import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.8.1/bootstrap-table.min.css); 
            h2{
                font-family: "Hypatia Sans Pro"
                }
            </style>
    ...
    </table>
```

As you can see, my fonts are neither monospace or cursive because the bootstrap stylesheets override it:

[image]

Comment: My first guess would be that the browser you're using doesn't support this attribute and treats it like a standard style. http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped

Comment: Whether it will, when `style scoped` is implemented in browsers, work there is unknown, but note that it is not HTML5.1-valid for `style scoped` to be a child of a `table` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I have found this reply online:**

You are not doing anything wrong. As of this moment, scoped CSS is still an experimental feature which is not supported by any current browser.

However, if you want to play around with it in Chrome you can do the following thing:

Go to chrome://flags/ in your Chrome browser;
Find "Enable experimental WebKit features." and click enable
Restart your browser.
Try your code. It should work.